# RedGate SQL tools v Microsoft Visual Studio Team System Database Edition (Data Dude)

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, sql-server-data-tools, redgate, datadude

I've been looking at RedGate's SQL tools and Microsofts Visual Studio Team System Database Edition (formerly Data Dude) for use within a testing and continuous integration environment.

What we need to be able to do is have:

- Schema and Data under source control
- Automated continuous integration using TeamCity (command line)
- Push changes (and data) to
  environments (staging, production,
  test) but not from Visual Studio

What solution would best fit our needs and what are peoples opinions, views and experiences of both products. Which did/would you choose and why? Are there any alternatives that I have missed?

Comment: Just for completeness, MS released a free stand-alone tool in SSDT that lets you create SQL Projects. It can put schema and some data scripts under source control, supports a command line to push the changes, and you can push your projects to different environments without needing Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this SO question [Source Control tools for Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 scripts and database updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653599/)